# Why does the Android OS use so much battery power?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, battery-life

Most of the time, I have enough power for my Samsung Galaxy SIII to operate for the whole day; at the end of the day my battery charge is about 35%. However, today, the battery died prematurely. I noticed the battery usage screen, and it says that 28% of the battery is used by the Android OS. How could this have happened?

**EDIT:** My question has been marked as a duplicate, but the target does not have any solution, so those answers do not fully address my question. Though I agree in the fact that this question is the same as the target.

Comment: Whether or not something is a duplicate is not generally decided by the answers provided, but by the content of the questions themselves, so your last statement seems rather confusing. If you agree that the questions are the same but find the answers lacking, consider adding a [bounty](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: Check betterbatterystats [free XDA version](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1179809) Or paid on [Google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats)

Comment: What you're looking for is wakelocks. That will explain what is pegging your processor/antenna.

Comment: @eldarerathis Not really. The intent of closing a question as a duplicate is to make sure that there is a canonical answer to the same question. Thus, when closing as a dupe, the main intent is to see if there is an answer at the linked question, not *so much* if the questions are identical. This is official advice from the SE team; that's why they removed the ability for non-mods to close questions as dupes when the target is considered unanswered.